# To find previous/next value in Sql server IN condition

Tags: sql-server

Say I have a IN condition (11,22,32,34,44,55), I know my parameter is now 32. Is it possible to find my parameter's current position and get the previous (here 22) or next (34) value? If so, what's the best way?

I got several notes with note_num. It's easy to get the first note and last note by using max and min. But I want to get next or previous note. What's the best way to do it?

Comment: Can you give an example of some values in your source table, and what your expected query output would be when applied against those examples?

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve for? If you want to search for a certain parameter why don't you just do `select blah where value = @parameter`?

Comment: I think you should edit your question to provide more detail, and a better description of what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not with an `IN` clause, no.  If you have SQL Server 2012 or above you can use the `LAG` and `LEAD` window functions to retrieve an expression based on the the previous or next record **that matched a value** in your conditions.

You could also create a table (fixed or temporary) with your values and join to that instead of using the `IN` clause. So your table `FilterValues` might look like:

```
Position             Value
-------------------- -----------
1                    11
2                    22
3                    32
4                    34
5                    44
6                    55
```

Then join to this table:

```
select Mytable.*, Position
from Mytable
join FilterValues
on Mytable.Value = FilterValues.Value
```

Now you have the position in the list.

Answer (score 2):

No it is not possible. `IN` is just like an `OR` clause.

As far as knowing the value previous to it and next to it you have to do it manually.